# How to scrape a Handlebar.js script in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, handlebars.js

I am trying to scrape the Euronorm and the CO2 from a list of cars from an auction website. I have so far succeeded in navigating to the correct auction webpage and downloading that webpage using Selenium. The information that I need is the `{{CO2Emission}}` and `{{EmissionClass}}` for all the cars in the following script:

```html
<script id="lot-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li data-id="{{Id}}">
        <a href="{{LotUrl}}">
            {{#if IsFollowing}}<figcaption><i class="fa fa-star"></i></figcaption>{{/if}}
            <img src="{{ImagePath}}" alt="{{LocaleName}}" />
        </a>
        <div class="list-info">
            <h3>
                <a class="car-title" href="{{LotUrl}}">{{LocaleName}}</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="item-specs">
                <li>Objectnumber: {{Number}}</li>
                {{#if EngineSize}}
                <li>CC: {{EngineSize}}</li>{{/if}}
                <li>Fuel: {{FuelType}}</li>
                {{#if PowerKW}}
                <li>KW: {{PowerKW}}</li>{{/if}}
                {{#if CO2Emission}}
                <li>CO2: {{CO2Emission}} g/km</li>{{/if}}
                {{#if EmissionClass}}
                <li>Euronorm: {{EmissionClass}}</li>{{/if}}
                {{#if FirstInUse}}
                <li> First Registration: {{date FirstInUse}}</li>{{/if}}
                {{#if Mileage}}
                <li>Counter: {{Mileage}} {{MileageType}}</li>{{/if}}
                {{#if Location}}
                <li>Location {{Location}}</li>{{/if}}
                {{#if LicensePlate}}
                <li>License plate {{LicensePlate}}</li>{{/if}}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btnrow">
            
            {{#if HasBid}}
            <span class="extra">My bid (Excl VAT): <strong>&euro; {{BidAmount}}</strong></span>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if IsOpenForBids}}
            <a href="{{BidUrl}}" class="btn fancyboxIframe fancybox.ajax"><i class="fa fa-gavel"></i>{{#if HasBid }}Change Bid{{else}}Bid now{{/if}}</a>
            {{/if}}
            <a class="btn" href="{{LotUrl}}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> details</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

Is it possible to get the information out of this script? I am a bit stuck now and I would like to know how to proceed. I am new to web scraping, so I am just trying stuff at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to get the information you need from this handlebars template. The template is combined with data to produce HTML, therefore you have two options for extracting the data you need:

- Parse the HTML that is generated with this template
- Find the source of the data that gets fed into this template

The source of the data may be an API, or in some form that does not require  scraping, so I would try that first, then try parsing HTML.

It would be useful to know which site/page you are trying to scrape.